# What are (algebraic) equations, really?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a much more philosophical question that I'm used to asking, but it's been nagging at me a bit.  Let's say I have an algebraic equation $y = x$, $x, y, \in \mathbb{R}$.  The best interpretation I have for this is: for any given $x$, you produce a $y$ with the same value.  But, philosophically I have some issues:

1) Why am I allowed to choose an $x$ in the first place, and how do I know that the equation will produce a $y$ for every $x$ I choose?  It's "obvious" that it does, but it seems like this is a sneaky way of saying something about the operator "=" that is often left out of textbooks.

2) What about more complicated equations that involve algebraic operations, like $y = x^2$?  I need to define certain operations, like multiplication, in order for this to work.  However, this isn't very satisfying.  For example, the real numbers form a field and therefore in order to define multiplication we require  $\forall x \ne 0 \exists x^{-1} | x*x^{-1} = 1$.  But how do we really know that this exists for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

am I just going way too deep into an ultimately meaningless question?

Comment: I would not look at it in a way that an $x$ *produces* an $y$, but rather as a *relation* on the set of $\mathbb R^2 \ni (x,y)$.

Comment: So you're saying that all pairs $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfy the relation already exist, independent of my description, and my description is just a useful way to talk about the pairs?

Comment: Generally when you think of e.g. a *line* or of a *plane*, you consider a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ that satisfies some conditions, for example an equation $ax+by+c=0$ or $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$.

Comment: You can't tell what color a widget is unless you know what a widget is. You can't tell whether non-zero reals have inverses unless you have a def'n of R and show that something exists that satisfies this def'n. This leads to "foundational " topics, which are  covered in texts on set-theory...... And what IS the def'n of R ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation $y=x$ is a predicate about the variables $y,x$.  It may be true or false.  For each possible pair $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, some pairs satisfy the equation and some do not.  Hence the equation partitions $\mathbb{R}^2$ into those pairs that satisfy the equation, and the rest.  It is possible that all pairs satisfy the equation, or that none do.

It is common to draw $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a pair of perpendicular axes, and indicate the satisfying pairs for a given equation as dots.  This is called the graph of the equation.

---

As for your second question, in order to meaningfully talk about $\mathbb{R}$, much less $\mathbb{R}^2$, we need to have a mathematical definition for it.  Part of this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) includes the field axioms.  Unfortunately, the definition is pretty complicated, and students are taught to use $\mathbb{R}$ before they really understand that definition.